# How to charge the HTC One X with power-off / display-off

Tags: screen, htc-one-x

I used to power off my phone at night while charging when I was using Desire S. Recently I bought HTC One X and can't charge with power off anymore. It keep turning on with the battery and bolt logo and display don't turn off. If I press the power button, the phone is boot again into Android. Now I have to turn on Airplain mode at night when charging. Am I the only one who encounter that problem because I doubt that is happening as I unlocked bootloader. I ain't sure as I unlocked the bootloader since the day I bought it. How can I charge with power off?

Comment: Normally once it's shown the battery charging icon for a few seconds, the screen should just turn itself off again.

Comment: @DanHulme Are you using HTC One X? Did you unlock your bootloader? It's not few second. The screen don't turn off till I sleep. I don't like the screen turning on so I just power on and enable airplain mode.

Comment: No, I'm not using HTC One X, but the charging icon is a common feature, and that's how it usually works.

Comment: I have a HTC One X and I don't have this problem. Are you on a stock ROM or a custom ROM?

Comment: @1990clb JellyBean Sense 5 stock rom. I think that is not related to rom. It may be related to kernel or something... How long does it take to screen turn off?

Comment: @MinNaingOo I think you are right. If you are rooted, flash a different kernel.
I am using a custom rom & kernel so my display is always off while charging with power off

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Min, but that is a built in feature that I believe one **cannot** change. Could you cover up the screen with something at night or just turn it over?

Comment: I have a HTC One X and it doesn't do this... Do you have one?

Comment: No, but its happened on all my Androids, and maybe its due to location, firmware level etc, as this kind of thing does vary from place to place - i.e you might have different model codes from Min.

Comment: My Desire S didn't have this problem. My Nook Color turn on while plug the charger when device turned off but turning off while charging was ok. Don't know what's wrong with this one x. Yes, I could turn it over but I just don't want it to turn on the display all night long. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've done this, but try turning off  the stay awake setting while charging?

1. From the Home screen, tap All apps.
2. Tap Settings.
3. Tap Developer options.
4. Tap to check Stay awake.

Comment: Hi Tony, I believe Stay awake option is for charging while phone is powered on.